# how to connect p5 glove with blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, blender

i try to do project about control model in blender by using p5 glove ,but i don't know how to connect it with blender game engine

Answer (score 0):

as you want to transfere information form p5 gloves to blender you need to transfere such info. via a protocol acting as listener to a specific port to listen for incoming data that comes form p5 glove ..

the most common used protocol is called OSC (Open Sound Contol)

http://www.deepfriedconcepts.com/blog/2010/communicating-between-blender-game-engine-and-processing/

see this link it will be so helpful ..

download their example "motion2blender" and you will get happy

Answer (score 0):

You can use "VRPN" which is an indication to the Virtual Reality Peripherals

Networks that works as simple network of client and server, where the connection between

your peripherals and the software that acts as client for accepting the transfered data

has to be done through the server

see this http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/vrpn/vrpn_support.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to connect the p5 glove with the Blender game engine. However, there are some unofficial methods that may work. One method is to use a third-party software application that can act as a bridge between the two applications. Another method is to use a hardware device that can act as a bridge between the two applications.

whichever method you choose, it is important to make sure that the software and hardware are compatible with both the p5 glove and the Blender game engine. Additionally, you may need to consult with a qualified technician to ensure that the connection is made properly and that the data is transmitted correctly.

One unofficial way to connect the p5 glove with the Blender game engine is to use a third-party software application that can act as a bridge between the two applications. Some examples of such software include GlovePIE and GloveConnect. Another unofficial way to connect the p5 glove with the Blender game engine is to use a hardware device that can act as a bridge between the two applications. An example of such a hardware device is the GlovePort.